# Cannot install company app on windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, code-signing, xap, code-signing-certificate

We are developing a company app for windows phone 8.

I have followed every step described in [Company app distribution for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206943%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Here is what I did:

- Registered company account
- Bought an enterprise certificate from Symantec.
- Exported PFX file with private key
- Generated Enrollment Token (AETX file) from PFX.
- Developed application, built with visual studio and get xap file
  generated. (Name it App.xap)
- Precompiled managed assemblies and Signed it with certificate using
  BuildMDILXap.ps1 powershell script. (All messages indicated success).
- Hosted AETX and signed XAP file on our web server.

At this point, when a wp8 phone tries to download XAP file without first installing AETX, The phone gives proper error message: "Before you install this app, you need to add XXXX company account. Contact your company's support person for help".

After installing AETX, when wp8 phone tries to install XAP file, the phone asks for confirmation: "Would you like to install App1 from XXXX?" After clicking "install" button, nothing happens. There is no success message, no error message, no indication of installation, and the application does not show in application list.

I have also tried sending AETX and XAP files over email (in case internet explorer or iis cannot handle file types), same result.

I have also tried doing the same for our company hub app, same result.

As far as I understand, company hub app is just another app (of course for different purpose) and both normal app and hub app can be distributed same way (over web address or email etc), right?

What is wrong? Cannot find the problem here?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I bet you don't have a proper setup for code signing. One important step that is easy to miss is to **install the parent certificates** of your enterprise code signing certificate (that you got from Symantec). Specifically, download and import the following two certificates and then try to sign the XAP file again.

https://knowledge.verisign.com/library/VERISIGN/ALL_OTHER/Symantec_Enterprise_Mobile_Root_for_Microsoft.cer
https://knowledge.verisign.com/library/VERISIGN/ALL_OTHER/Symantec_Enterprise_Mobile_CA_for_Microsoft_Cert.cer

It is sad that the signing tool does not report any errors, yet the output is not a correctly signed XAP that WP8 would accept.

Comment: I will try your suggestion first thing in the morning. Thanks for the tip. Any other suggestion if it does not work?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Reinstalling those certificates on computer that I generate AET and make the signing worked. It is so unfortunate that tool does not report any error or message.

Comment: I am having a similar problem, however I do have both of those certs installed and when viewing my cert I see it is a child of Mobile CA which is a child of Mobile Root. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422099/windows-phone-8-error-installation-of-the-application-failed

Comment: I have a similar issue, Installing signed app after enrolling in the company using aetx was working for months on my device Lumia 720 - Wp8.1 preview. Now after I click the confirmation message nothing happens!, I tried on another device (lumia 630 with cyan) and It's working. What do you think is the problem with my device? Will it happen with other devices when I distribute it?