# WP8 Company Hub app - AddPackageAsync() not installing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a windows phone 8 application which functions as a company app hub.

It will be used to install assigned company apps, which are hosted on a server.

I am attempting to test the InstallationManager.AddPackageAsync() function for installing assigned applications through the app.  I created a empty test assigned app (just a title screen) and packaged and signed the .xap file, following all the steps here: [Company App Distribution for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206943%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

So I have hosted my company hub app, as well as this test assigned company app, on the server (both of them signed, and the device is enrolled using the AET generated as described in the above link.)

I install the company hub app fine, the hub app discovers the available assigned application and attempts to install it using AddPackageAsync, it prompts the user "Would you like to install AssignedCompanyApp from MyCompany?"

However, upon clicking "install" and the dismissal of the prompt dialog, nothing happens - the app is not installed.  I do not see it listed, and it does not show up after searching with InstallationManager.FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher();

I do not think this is a signing problem - the device is enrolled and both the hub app and the test assigned app were precompiled and signed with our PFX file.

Additionally, when I simply navigate the phone to the test assigned app .xap file in Internet Explorer, it downloads, installs, and runs fine, and it shows up when the hub app subsequently runs FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher().

Here is the code in question:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(@"http://www.myServer.com/xaps/MyAssignedCompanyApp.xap");
InstallationManager.AddPackageAsync("My Assigned Company App", uri);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot install company app on windows phone 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416437/cannot-install-company-app-on-windows-phone-8)

Comment: I saw that question before posting.  Unless I am mistaken, this is a different issue.  That question involves not being able to install the company hub app, and seems to be a signing issue.  My company hub app installs fine, it just doesn't seem to successfully install OTHER assigned applications using the InstallationManager.AddPackageAsync() command.

Comment: Perhaps my question wasn't clear, and I apologize.  My company hub app is signed correctly and installs correctly OTA.  This app shows other available (signed) company apps and attempts to download them with AddPackageAsync().  This prompts the user but doesn't seem to download.  Please also note that the other assigned company app in question also installs fine OTA when I attempt that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call AppPackageAsync as asynchronous method, as in the example:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(@"http://www.myServer.com/xaps/MyAssignedCompanyApp.xap");
await InstallationManager.AddPackageAsync("My Assigned Company App", uri);
```