# How to install .xap files in Windows 8 Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I just download windows phone application (*.XAP) from  Mail, but how to install it to my Nokia Lumia?
My windows phone is developwer unlocked.
 When my download is completed and i click on application than it give Error message like

"Can't install company app.
There's problem with this company app.
Contact your company's support person for help."**

Comment: Take a look at this one, HTH: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416437/cannot-install-company-app-on-windows-phone-8