# Is it possible to install xap file like apk in android through mail attachment

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, xap

Is it possible to install my windowsphone app's "XAP" file through mail attachment.

That  means download xap file from mail and install it in mobile device.

Can anybody help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems theres another possibilty than this

1 - from store

2 - using the app deployment tool

Go through this link

[App Deployment in windows phone](http://windowsphonehub.in/blog/)

Heres the Crack can try if you have  adevice.

[Install xap from mail attachments.](http://www.wpxbox.com/xap-handler-install-app-wp-ie-root-custom-rom/)

Answer (score 0):

Reffare below link

[Cannot install company app on windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416437/cannot-install-company-app-on-windows-phone-8)

as per my experience we can not download xap file from mail and install it in mobile device.

it give messae like

**"Can't install company app. There's problem with this company app. Contact your company's support person for help."**

Comment: if any query let me know