# "Can't install company app" on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, code-signing, xap, code-signing-certificate

I've developed a company app for Windows Phone 8, and have gone through all the recommended steps to set it up for installation. I have a Symantec code-signing certificate, and I have generated my Application Enrollment Token and my signed XAP, which I am hosting in a public folder on OneDrive. I generated the XAP using the BuildMDILXap.ps1 script, which ran without errors. I haven't bothered with a company hub app, since we're only distributing a single app.

The AET loads OK on the phone, and asks if I would like to add the workplace account. I click "add", the dialogue box disappears, and no error comes up. There is no confirmation message, however I don't know if I should expect one.

When I load up the XAP, I get the message "Can't install company app. There's a problem with this company app. Contact your company's support person for help."

The phone has been developer unlocked (which of course isn't necessary), and I've had the app side-loaded and running on it successfully before. It was uninstalled before attempting the above, however.

I'm not sure what to do from here. I've tried recompiling and re-signing the XAP and re-generating the AET, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Before anyone asks, I have seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416437/cannot-install-company-app-on-windows-phone-8?rq=1

I have installed the parent certificates, so that isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fruitlessly trying to solve this problem, I found a workaround that does what I need.

It turns out that you can post apps to the **public app store**, but **hide them from searches**, essentially making them private to anyone that doesn't have the link. That solves my first problem, getting the app published in a way that my client can access without me needing to have developer licenses for each of their phones.

The **downside** with that solution is that you still have to wait a few days for an update to be approved, which isn't the greatest when you're still beta-testing and need to make quick changes. However, Microsoft also have a **beta program** for Windows Phone apps. By designating the app as Beta, **submission happens automatically within 2 hours**, but you have to restrict access to specific Microsoft accounts. The latter isn't a problem because the number of devices using the app is relatively small.

This removes the need for a corporate app store in my case, and saves the expense of a certificate and the fiddling around that goes with it.

Comment: Where is this option for beta, please? I did not find

Comment: I haven't tried this for a while now, so I expect the options have changed. I will probably be doing it again soon, however, so I'll post back here when I've figured it out.