# How to build a XAP file in Xamarin (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-mobile, xamarin.forms

Iam new to Xamarin, I have developed a test(dummy) app in Xamarin.forms. My client wants to test all the three(iOS,Android & windows) generated apps on his devices.

I managed to get the APK file (referred link:[how-to-build-your-android-app-for-testing-in-visual-studio](http://www.sweet-web-design.com/wordpress/how-to-build-your-android-app-for-testing-in-visual-studio/2581/)). The android apk seems to be working on the device.

I also managed to get PhoneApp1_Release_ARM.xap by building the app under release mode. But the xap file when run on windows device does not work. I get error:

```
Can't install company app
There's a problem with this company app. Contact your company's support person for help.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you not able to physically connect the device to your computer to do a proper side-load? Not sure if you will be able to simply send an iOS App to them to load on their device without it being connected.

Comment: I have to send the app files to my client for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Before distributing a company app or a Company Hub app to employees or other users, you must prepare the app for distribution by performing the following tasks:

- Precompile any managed assemblies that are included in the package into native code.
- Sign the package with the enterprise certificate that you obtained from Symantec. For more info about obtaining the certificate, see Company app distribution for Windows Phone.

go to this link for detail description about
[Preparing company apps for distribution for Windows Phone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/dn168929%28v%3Dvs.105%29)

check this solution also - [Cannot install company app on windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416437/cannot-install-company-app-on-windows-phone-8?rq=1)